# Can AWS Amplify be used with MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, aws-amplify

We are evaluating both AWS Amplify and MeteorJS for a new project, and I am wondering of both can be used together; use Amplify inside a Meteor app and publish the app on AWS.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, Yanick, did you do this? I have a similar case, I want to use amplify and express and publish the app on AWS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the integration areas but I see a lot of overlapping in terms of results. Would you think of using the Amplify React components into a Meteor project or a certain part of Amplify?